# How do I fix my grub issue?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, grub

A while ago I installed android shell alongside windows 10, but when I didn't need it anymore and tried uninstalling it, but I
didn't uninstall it correctly, and I left a broken grub behind and gave me an error 15 on the next boot, so I used a ubuntu installation usb and ran the command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=446 count=1` in the ubuntu terminal, but when I booted next it showed an error 17, when I tried to use a windows installation usb and and made it only boot from USB, the grub gave this error:`error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.`.

Comment: 1. You may have just deleted the Windows system partition. 2. If you were actually booting from the Windows installation media no Grub related errors would be shown, ever! The problem is you AREN'T booting from the USB for whatever reason (maybe you should ask about that?). And in any case, in proper UEFI mode, all it takes after removing one OS is to open UEFI settings > Boot menu and change the boot order / OS selection to the other, in this case, "Windows bootloader manager".

Comment: Why would it be booting from something other than the windows usb if I had all other options disabled in bios? Maybe I have a faulty USB stick? I should also clarify I'm using legacy boot mode.

Comment: Maybe because it isnt bootable? This is the #1 mistake... How exactly have you made it? If you're using Legacy in a UEFI machine, any from ~2012 or newer then there's exactly where you're `problems start. Right now you indeed need to boot Windows Installation media and follow instructions to repair the bootloader.

Comment: I used the windows 10 media creation tool to create an iso file on another computer and put the iso onto a USB, but now that I think about it, I might have been supposed to use rufus

Comment: No, you *can* use Rufus but if downloading the ISO from Windows the Media Creation tool does it all. Copying the ISO to the drive won't work, obviously, unless you have Ventoy already installed.

Comment: Alright, I haven't used this website before, so how do I mark it as answered?

Comment: You don't because there's no answer posted. Comments aren't answers. I could post one - after all I immediately identified the problem - but really there's no point. This is the same that has been asked and answered thousands of times, some questions was marked as duplicates of others, others just deleted when abandoned. This really doesn't help anyone else so...

Comment: These are only comments. You can't mark a comment as an answer. Sometimes the answer comes out in the conversations in comments. If a specific comment solved your problem, one common method is to tell the commenter they solved it for you, ask them to post that as an answer, and once they do you mark that as THE answer. If you just used a helpful hint to find the full answer yourself, YOU write out and post the answer, and, usually after 24 hours, you can mark that as the answer.

Comment: And, as @ChanganAuto notes, this question has been asked several times before: https://superuser.com/search?q=error%3A+file+%27%2Fboot%2Fgrub%2Fi386-pc%2Fnormal.mod%27+not+found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computer won't boot. UEFI DUET](https://superuser.com/questions/504377/computer-wont-boot-uefi-duet)